# MySQL on Select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to select all data from a table.
I have a database named "registered_users" and it has a table named "user_email". 
I want to check all.

As it checks to see if email is registered and then redirect to a page...
Right now it is selecting from the last one that has been inputted.
I want to check all emails for every ID.

```
    $querygetusermain = "SELECT * FROM registered_users";
    $resgetusermain   = mysql_query($querygetusermain);

    $reals = "SELECT * FROM `registered_users` ORDER BY `registered_users`.`id`  DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $realss   = mysql_query($reals);
    $realssrow   = mysql_num_rows($realss);
    while($realssss= @mysql_fetch_array($realss)){
    $register = $realssss['user_email'];
```

Comment: That is what `LIMIT 0,1` does when combined with an `ORDER BY field(s) DESC`

Comment: Learn to give better names to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have a row limiter on your query.

```
$querygetusermain = "SELECT * FROM registered_users";
$resgetusermain   = mysql_query($querygetusermain);
$reals = "SELECT * FROM registered_users ORDER BY id";
$realss = mysql_query($reals);
$realssrow = mysql_num_rows($realss);
while ($realssss= mysql_fetch_array($realss)) {
     $register = $realssss['user_email'];
```

Comment: This above code does not work at all either. In fact not any email works now.